# Invoice for solicitors fees when selling house in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, fees

We have had conflicting information:

1. Some solicitors take their fees (balance) prior to transfer of sale funds to seller.
2. Solicitor must submit invoice prior to disbursement, and that seller can insist on transfer of all funds (excluding monies owed to Building Society) prior to paying solicitor.

Which is legally correct, and if the solicitor's fees are not acceptable, what is the redress in case 1?

Comment: Loosely related: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21947/when-buying-selling-a-house-in-the-uk-is-it-normal-for-solicitors-fees-to-be

Comment: Much of this - including the solicitor's fees - should be discussed with the solicitor before you begin proceedings. It's usually up to you and them to agree how things are going to work, and what it will cost.

Answer (score 2):

UK Solicitor fees are set according to the solicitor.  Negotiate how much and when they are paid with the solicitor.

> The Costs
>
> Solicitors either charge a fixed fee (usually between £250
> and £750), or a percentage of your house's sales price (usually 0.5%).
> Make sure you get some quotes before choosing a solicitor and agree on
> his fee, in writing, before instruction.

[Source](http://www.home.co.uk/guides/selling/conveyancing.htm)